# How to print without skipping a line php

Tags: html, css

I have a code for a hangman game and it prints out the blank spaces something like something like

```
a
_
b
c
_
_
```

but it does it veritcally and I need it horizontally. This is my code

```
echo '<div style="margin: auto;width: 100%;margin-left: 40%;border-radius: 4px;font-weight: bold;" class="words">'.$char.'</div>';
```

Comment: "If an answer solved your problem, consider accepting the answer. Here's [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Then return here and do the same with the tick/check-mark till it turns green. This informs the community, a solution was found. Otherwise, others may think the question is still open and may want to post (more) answers. You'll earn points and others will be encouraged to help you. Welcome to Stack!"

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `<span>` which has `display: inline` CSS value instead of `<div>` element that has `display: block` CSS value which cause each element to be on different line.

```css
.words {
  background: #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<span class="words">a</span>
<span class="words">_</span>
<span class="words">b</span>
<span class="words">c</span>
<span class="words">_</span>
<span class="words">_</span>
```

Translated in PHP for your use-case:

```
echo '<span class="words">'.$char.'</span>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `display: inline-block;` to the style tag of the div.

Divs take up a whole "line" when rendering.

Anyway, you should do like Anant suggested. Create a class and use it instead of repeating the style prop inside the div tag.

Answer (score 0):

Don't print an html tag around each character. You're better off with something like this:

```css
.chars{
   font-size: 24px;
   letter-spacing: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="chars">_ a b _ _ c</div>
```

In php, that might look like this:

```
echo "<div class='chars'>";
foreach($chars as $char){
   echo $char;
}
echo "</div>";
```